# Как сделать код в js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("[data-link]").click(function(e){
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-link');
});
```

Помогите преобразовать код на Vanilla.JS, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ваш код уже на JS, вы хотите убрать jQuery?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) - создание массива из массивоподобного объекта.
[`Document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - поиск элементов по CSS-селектору.
[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) - перебор массива.
[`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - назначение элементу слушатель события.
[`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) - доступ к элементам `data` (пользовательские данные).

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-link]")).forEach(e =>
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    window.location.href = this.dataset.link;
  })
);
```

Comment: сильно, красиво :) vaniiilla :)

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ванилька всегда хороша. Во всех смыслах :)

Comment: Получаю ошибку в Console: 

scripts.js:4 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

В файле постороннего кода нет

Comment: @dogmar, My bad, исправил.

Comment: @other  К сожалению, ошибка не пропала, она отображается даже в jsfiddle, попробуйте.

Comment: @dogmar, Теперь точно работает.